# How can I bind a default value on dropdown select using Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

I have a form update on my page and I already implemented a binding value and I can show it on a plain text. My problem is how can I select this by default?

Here's my code:

```
<select 
    id="coursewareType"
    name="courseware_type"
    class="form-field"
    ng-model="$ctrl.questionnaire.data.attributes.category"
    ng-required="$ctrl.QuestionnaireStore.questionnaireFormMode !== 'detail'"
    ng-options="opt.label for opt in $ctrl.questionnairewareType">
</select>

<p>{{ $ctrl.questionnaire.data.attributes.category }}</p><!-- NO PROBLEM HERE I CAN GET THE SAVED DATA HERE. HOW CAN I MAKE THIS AS A DEFAULT SELECTED OPTION? -->
```

And on my controller I have my options values

```
//fields for type
questionnairewareType = [
    {
        value: "questionnaire",
        label: "Questionnaire"
    },
    {
        value: "course-content",
        label: "Course Content"
    }
];
```

On the backend part I need to pass the value of my dropdown.
I hope you can help me. Thanks all and thanks.

Comment: the code looks correct, if you put some object from `questionnairewareType` to `questionnaire.data.attributes.category`  in your controller then that object will be selected automatically, what is the problem do you have? Show us how do you fetch default option from server

Comment: and also, what value is stored in `questionnaire.data.attributes.category`, it is just a simple string, not an object?

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-value for default value it will select by default.

```
$scope.default_val = "course-content";
<select 
    id="coursewareType"
    name="courseware_type"
    class="form-field"
    ng-value="default_val"
    ng-model="$ctrl.questionnaire.data.attributes.category"
    ng-required="$ctrl.QuestionnaireStore.questionnaireFormMode !== 'detail'"
    ng-options="opt.label for opt in $ctrl.questionnairewareType">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign default value(object) to $ctrl.questionnaire.data.attributes.category:

`$ctrl.questionnaire.data.attributes.category = //questionnairewareType[0]` (dummy here)